# Using C# source generators (IIncrementalGenerator) can I generate code into a different project?

Tags: c#, .net, sourcegenerators

I am trying to write a source generator which implements `IIncrementalGenerator`. The generator needs to read a `struct` where all of the properties are constants, like this:

```
public struct MyStruct
{
    public const string Prop1 = "PROP1";
    // More properties
}
```

With the code below, I have successfully generated code into the same project as the `struct` above:

```
[Generator]
public class MyGenerator : IIncrementalGenerator
{
    public void Initialize(IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext context)
    {
        var structs = context.SyntaxProvider
          .CreateSyntaxProvider(
             (s, _) => s is StructDeclarationSyntax sds,
             (c, _) =>
             {
                 return (c.Node is StructDeclarationSyntax sds && sds.Identifier.Text == "MyStruct")
                     ? sds
                     : null;
             }
          )
          .Where(x => x != null)
          .Collect();

        context.RegisterSourceOutput(structs, GenerateSource);
    }

    private void GenerateSource(SourceProductionContext context, ImmutableArray<StructDeclarationSyntax?> structs)
    {            
        string myCode = // my generated code
        context.AddSource($"MyCode.g.cs", myCode);
    }
}
```

Now I would like to generate additional code into a different project. Is this possible with `IncrementalGeneratorInitializationContext` and `SourceProductionContext`?

Some thoughts:

- Is `AdditionalTextsProvider` the way to go here?
- Should I write a new generator in the other project, and try to access `MyStruct` which is in the original project? If so, how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to go in the opposite direction.  Write your source generator so that it resides in one project and scans the project assembly as well as any referenced assemblies.

Take a look at this guy's project as an example:

https://github.com/martinothamar/Mediator